# Change an environment variable in between Jenkins build steps

Tags: batch-file, groovy, jenkins, hudson

I have a Jenkins job with a string parameter called `MyPath`, a groovy script build step and then a batch command build step.

If I kicked off a job so that the value of `MyPath` is "`C:\Temp\`", I want the groovy script to change the value of `MyPath` to be "`C:\Temp\3.4\setup.exe`" and then I want to use the batch file to execute `MyPath`.

I know I can launch a process from groovy and that I can perform my groovy logic in batch, it would just be nice if I could pass variables between build steps.

To use a parameter in groovy you have to use the library to resolve it (below). Is there a method that can set it?

```
def path = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("MyPath");
```

Something like this would be perfect if it existed:

`buildVariableChanger.change("MyPath") = "C:\3.4\setup.exe"`

I have also looked into the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin but from what I understand it does not support what I want to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible since field value for StringParameterValue.class is final: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/StringParameterValue.html

The solution may be creating other parameter in groovy script

```
import hudson.model.StringParameterValue
import hudson.model.ParametersAction

def newPath = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("MyPath") + "3.4\\setup.exe"
build.addAction(new ParametersAction (new StringParameterValue ('path2', newPath)))
```

and then use parameter path2 in batch command

Comment: Thank you, while the other answers worked, this is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One option should be to use the [SETX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) Windows command to set the value of user (or system) environment variable.

If you set this variable in your Groovy step, then the batch step should be able to use it.

Comment: I did a quick test on a Windows 2008 R2 server.
setx MY_VAR "the value".
The variable is not available in the current dos command Windows.
But if I open a new dos command, I can see the MY_VAR variable with a set command.
So you don't need a reboot to set a variable with setx.
Maybe this solution will work, to be tested...

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the downvote. Please edit your answer somehow so I can upvote it.

Comment: This would be a good workaround for my problem, however, I think it would be neater if everything was handled within Jenkins if possible. It looks like @jussuper has the solution I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply pass a variable to your batch? You could start the batch from your first script instead of starting it with an own build step. Just call it with `yourscript.bat C:\3.4\setup.exe`. You can access the argument with `%1`. If you insert the line `%1` into your bat file it will execute `C:\3.4\setup.exe`.

Comment: As I said below, the SETX command can change a value without a restart.

Comment: Just tested it, you are right. Modified my answer. Sorry.

Comment: This is definitely a possible solution however I would like to keep all the code in the Jenkins job because I find it is easier to maintain. I'm actively trying to reduce the amount of code I have in batch files outside of Jenkins because keeping them organised is annoying. I suppose I could deliver the batch file using the `Provide Configuration Files` option but having the code somewhere would still bug me.